# Convert a PRN or OXPS file to PDF file

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I have the following situation.

I am working with the ZPL language of Zebra, I have to make some modifications to the ticket we printed. The situation is that I cannot make use of physical print so I cannot see the modifications I make.

I am investigating the way to see the printing of the ticket digitally but I have not achieved it, I have already installed a virtual pdf printer, I have tried to convert the `.prn` `.oxps` files but I can only obtain the following:

```
FK"*"
N
R00,0
O
q672
Q1500,B30+38
S5
D11
ZT
A010,50,0,2,1,1,N,"*e-"
A090,50,0,2,1,1,N,"TRADEMARK:"
A280,50,0,3,1,1,N,"TRADEMARK EXAMPLE"
...................
```

That I want is to see something like that in a pdf file:

[image]

I really don't know if what I'm looking for is possible. I want to see the format of the ticket in a pdf. Investigating I found ZPL Viewer where the zpl code is placed and shows the final ticket design, but the problem is that the ZPL encoding is different.

The coding I use is as follows:

```
FK"*"
N
R00,0
O
q672
Q1500,B30+38
S5
D11
ZT
A010,50,0,2,1,1,N,"*e-"
A090,50,0,2,1,1,N,"TRADEMARK:"
A280,50,0,3,1,1,N,"<lbl_trademark>"
............
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://labelary.com/

Also, the network printers will let you log into them through the network and preview ZPL. Just browse to the printer's IP address in your browser.